# >Javascript Comparing 2 dates

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this code in comparing dates

```
var startDate = jQuery("#startDate_field_id").val();
var endDate = jQuery("#endDate_field_id").val();
var startDateSplit = startDate.split("-");
var endDateSplit = endDate.split("-");
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
start.setFullYear( startDateSplit[0], startDateSplit[1], startDateSplit[2] );
end.setFullYear( endDateSplit[0], endDateSplit[1], endDateSplit[2] );

if( end < start ) {
 alert("End Date should be less than Start Date of the Event");
}
```

The value of #startDate_field_id is **2011-10-05**

white the value of $endDate_field_id is **2011-10-04**

What do you think is the reason why this isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded. 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first problem is that you are using the Date object incorrectly. You are passing three arguments to the setFullYear() method, which only takes a single argument, a 4 digit year.

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
start.setFullYear( startDateSplit[0], startDateSplit[1], startDateSplit[2] );
end.setFullYear( endDateSplit[0], endDateSplit[1], endDateSplit[2] );
```

You might want to try something like this:

```
var start = new Date(startDateSplit[0], startDateSplit[1] - 1, startDateSplit[2])
var end = new Date(endDateSplit[0], endDateSplit[1] - 1, endDateSplit[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use UNIX epoch timestamps for the comparison:

```
if (end.getTime() > start.getTime()) {
    alert('...');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping the values for start and end through alert() or into the DOM to make sure they're correct?

Answer (score 1):

Because setFullYear method month parameter accept 0..11, means 9 is October.

why not use

```
var start = new Date(startDate);
var end = new Date(endDate);
```

Comment: This a right way. But IE8 dont support date string in "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = new Date(Number(startDateSplit[0]), Number(startDateSplit[1])-1, Number(startDateSplit[2]));
var end = new Date(Number(endDateSplit[0]), Number(endDateSplit[1])-1, Number(endDateSplit[2]));
```

or simply:

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I correctly understand your question .

I guess you want make sure that the end date **must be greater than** start date.

your code will work fine if you cahnge the if condition .And i just changed the alert message too to get proper meaning

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/94LuH/)  .